# angular2-notification dependency on zone.js after angular update

Tags: angular, npm-install, zone.js, peer-dependencies

I upgraded my angular application to v16 and I'm getting below error after running npm install.

```
npm ERR! While resolving: angular2-notifications@12.0.0
npm ERR! Found: zone.js@0.13.1
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   zone.js@"~0.13.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer zone.js@"~0.13.0" from @angular/core@16.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!     @angular/core@"^16.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/core@"16.2.2" from @angular/animations@16.2.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!       @angular/animations@"^16.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       2 more (@angular/material, @angular/platform-browser)
npm ERR!     18 more (@angular/cdk, @angular/common, @angular/compiler, ...)
npm ERR!   1 more (primeng)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer zone.js@"^0.11.4" from angular2-notifications@12.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/angular2-notifications
npm ERR!   angular2-notifications@"12.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: zone.js@0.11.8
npm ERR! node_modules/zone.js
npm ERR!   peer zone.js@"^0.11.4" from angular2-notifications@12.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/angular2-notifications
npm ERR!     angular2-notifications@"12.0.0" from the root project
```

It's clear from the error that angular/core@16 requires Zone.js@0.13.1 and angular2-notifications@12.0.0(12 is the latest version) has a peer dependency on zone.js@0.11.4. Since angular2-notifications' version has been maxed out, is there any other way except to replace it to resolve this error?

Here's my dependencies and devDependencies from package.json for reference.

dependencies

```
"@angular-devkit/core": "16.2.0",
"@angular/animations": "^16.2.2",
"@angular/cdk": "^16.2.1",
"@angular/common": "^16.2.2",
"@angular/compiler": "16.2.2",
"@angular/core": "^16.2.2",
"@angular/forms": "^16.2.2",
"@angular/localize": "^16.2.2",
"@angular/material": "^16.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.2",
"@angular/router": "^16.2.2",
"@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.1.2",
"@daymon-nes/daymon-usermanagement-client": "3.0.1",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.1.1",
"@ng-select/ng-select": "^11.1.1",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
"@okta/okta-signin-widget": "6.3.0",
"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "20.1.0",
"@types/base-64": "^0.1.2",
"@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.36",
"@types/jquery": "3.3.34",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"angular2-notifications": "12.0.0",
"angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
"base-64": "^0.1.0",
"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"css-ripple-effect": "^1.0.5",
"file-saver": "^2.0.2",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.6",
"html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
"ionic-native": "2.2.11",
"jquery": "3.4.1",
"jspdf": "^2.4.0",
"knockout": "3.4.2",
"lato-font": "^3.0.0",
"libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.13",
"material-colors": "^1.2.5",
"material-design-iconic-font": "^2.2.0",
"messageformat": "^1.1.1",
"moment": "^2.20.1",
"multiple-date-picker-angular": "^3.0.0",
"ng2-date-picker": "^16.0.0",
"ng2-rx-componentdestroyed": "3.0.1",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
"ngx-bootstrap-multiselect": "^4.0.0",
"ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.0",
"ngx-mask": "^16.2.5",
"ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
"password-validator": "^4.1.1",
"popper": "^1.0.1",
"popper.js": "^1.12.9",
"primeng": "^16.1.0",
"prismjs": "^1.9.0",
"rimraf": "^2.6.2",
"rxjs": "^7.8.1",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
"rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
"string-mask": "^0.3.0",
"swimlane": "0.0.1",
"tether": "^1.3.7",
"tinymce": "^4.8.5",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"url": "^0.11.0",
"xlsx": "^0.17.3",
"zone.js": "~0.13.0"
```

devDependencies

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/cli": "^16.2.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "16.2.2",
"@angular/language-service": "^16.2.2",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/lodash": "4.14.116",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "~6.3.4",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~3.2.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "4.9.5"
```

Appreciate your help/suggestions.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

According to the above error, angular2-notifications@12.0.0 required a peer zone.js@"^0.11.4". But [angular2-notifications@12.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-notifications) yet not updated to compatible with latest version of zone.js. For that reason you'll not able to use angular2-notifications@12.0.0 with zone.js@0.13.1. You may use an alternative notification module like [angular-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-notifier).

```
> npm i angular-notifier
```